How to select a group of elements in codeBehind in Web Forms without generating a wrapper element
I have a Webform page with a html form in it. A group of fields are for customer data and another is for product data, and others are neither of these two groups.
I need to hide the whole group of products fields or customer fields in PageLoad or some other event handlers based on some backend logic. The problem is in .NET Framework, I need to hide them one by one by ID
which requires a huge bunch of code and I need to change the code anytime I add a new product or customer related field.
Grouping them into a wrapper and hide this wrapper instead breaks some CSS selectors as shown below where even display:contents won't help.
Is there anyway to "Pseudo Group" these elements in .NET Framework so that I can refer the group of elements in codeBeind either using for loop or whatever way to hide them, while the generated HTML won't actually have that extra wrapper layer? I'm not looking to rewrite the CSS selectors, as below is just an example and there are actually way more.
ProductFieldGroup.Visible = false;



.spaced-form>.input-group:not(:first-child) {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

/*wrapper that breaks some CSS selector*/
.product-fields {
  display:content;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="form-group spaced-form">
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text">Other Field 1</span>
    </div>
    <input runat="server" id="OtherField1" type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" />
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text">Customer Field 1</span>
    </div>
    <input runat="server" id="Customer1" type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" />
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text">Customer Field 2</span>
    </div>
    <input runat="server" id="Customer2" type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" />
  </div>
  <div class="product-fields" id="ProductFieldGroup">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">Product Field 1</span>
      </div>
      <input runat="server" id="Product1" type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" />
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">Product Field 2</span>
      </div>
      <input runat="server" id="Product2" type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" />
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">Other Field 2</span>
      </div>
      <input runat="server" id="OtherField1" type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" />
    </div>
  </div>

</div>




UPDATE:
The PlaceHolder component can be used if no markup should be generated.

Probably, you are looking for the Panel component.
It allows you to show/hide a group of controls/markup by setting the panel's Visible property in code-behind, among other things.
In your example, the group of product fields can be declared as:
<asp:Panel ID="ProductFieldsPanel" runat="server">
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text">Product Field 1</span>
        </div>
        <input runat="server" id="Product1" type="text" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text">Product Field 2</span>
        </div>
        <input runat="server" id="Product2" type="text" class="form-control" />
    </div>
</asp:Panel>

To hide those fields, in code-behind, you can write:
ProductFieldsPanel.Visible = false;

For hidden panels no markup is generated. On the other hand, the above panel generates the following markup when visible:
<div id="MainContent_ProductFieldsPanel">

Hope it helps.

Thank you! However, as you said, I noticed the panel is still generated as a div wrapper. My main goal is to not having this extra layer of div while still being able to do the ProductFieldsPanel.Visible = false in code-behind.

@SyndRain What about this then?

Yes Placeholder works perfectly, thank you! (Literal doesn't since it doesn't allow child control). If you could update your answer I'll mark this as accepted!

Just noticed MultiView and View doesn't generate extra div wrapper as well and is able switch between views easily (though not needed in my case so placeholder is enough).

@SyndRain Have updated my answer, thanks.
